# Re-run imported python module

Tags: python, import

Very new to Python and I have a very basic question (I fear it is so basic that I don't really know how to research this question in the archives).

I've created basic modules and can import them into Python 3.4.3 Shell. On import, the module runs once and only once. Attempts to use exec() or other functions hasn't been successful. I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but how can I re-run a module once it's been initially imported? Attempts to google this question has not been successful.

Answer (score 3):

**Normally you only define functions in modules.**

myModule.py

```
def myFunction(myArg):
    myArg = myArg + 1
    return myArg
```

main.py

```
import myModule
myModifiedValue = myModule.myFunction(myOriginalValue)
```

**Use the following to write tests for your modules:**

module.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if myFunction(5) != 6:
        print("Function doesn't work correctly!")
    else:
        print("Function works for argument '5'.")
```

The test will only be done if you run myModule.py, not if you import myModule.py in main.py

**If you really want to reload a module use the `reload` function.**

`reload` was moved to `imp.reload` in Python 3.x.The `reload` function should **NOT** be used to execute code directly in a module! You should use it only to reload the functions of a module.